# Proof of the associated Lie algebra is isomorphic to $T_e(G)$

Tags: differential-geometry

I´m looking for a book with the proof of the result that says the associated Lie algebra of a Lie group $G$, let be $G_{Lie}$, is isomorphic to the tangent space $T_e(G)$, where $e \in G$ is the neutral element.

Let me said the chapter or theorem, not only the book, please.

Thank you all

Comment: It's [Chapter $21$](http://bose.res.in/~amitabha/diffgeom/chap21.pdf), pages 81-84.

Comment: I thought that the lie algebra was *defined* to be the tangent space at the identity (with Lie bracket defined by bracket of vector fields, where we extend individual vectors to locally nice vector fields first). That would certainly make the proof easy. :)

Comment: Ah...I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: I asked a concrete book, not just notes. I asked a reference book. The link is only a doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd edition by John Lee (great book). This is theorem 8.37, page 191.